# Поместить данные в фиксированные места шаблона

Tags: c#, xml, serialize

Приветствую!

Возможно такое реализовать? И  подскажите, пожалуйста, как это делается?

Допустим у меня есть шаблон (иерархическая структура) типа:

```
security {
    policies {
        from-zone **DmzGi** to-zone *UntrustGi* {
            policy *519* {
                match {
                    source-address *172.16.2.2/32*;
                    destination-address *172.16.3.2/32*;
                    application *any*;
                }
                then {
                    *reject*;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

1. Здесь звездочками -это данные, которые получаю из текстового файла (используя регулярки) ( помещаю в класс). (Это, допустим, уже умею).
2. Из этих классов могу делать XML - сериализацией (тоже умею).

   ```
    <security>
       <policies>
           <policy>
               <from-zone-name>TrustGi</from-zone-name>
               <to-zone-name>UntrustGi</to-zone-name>
               <policy>
                   <name>554</name>
                   <match>
                       <source-address>Noyabrsk_inet.ycc.ru_pool</source-address>
                       <destination-address>yarik_inet1ycc.ru_pool</destination-address>
                       <application>ANY</application>
                  </match>
               </policy>
        </policies>
    </security>
   ```
3. Как сделать так , чтобы данные из тегов XML попали в нужные места в первой иерархической схемы.
4. Может, даже и, не создавая XML, сразу из классов эти данные попадали в нужные фиксированные места.
5. И вот эта схема (шаблон) –она же как-то должна где-то хранится в каком-то файле( что за тип этого файла будет).

Comment: Хм. Вам придётся писать ещё одну, кастомную сериализацию для ваших классов. То есть чтобы `Security`, `Policy` и все остальные умели сериализоваться не только в XML, но и в ваш исходный формат. Это по идее ничуть не сложнее.

Comment: Спасибо! как и всегда! А можете указать на подробный пример в Инете?

Comment: @vlazarev: нет, подробного примера я не знаю. :( Но когда-то писал подобное. Идея приблизительно такая: http://pastebin.com/K6Z5gsjM

---
Исправил: http://pastebin.com/Ugst43tC (общий тег policies должен быть сериализован на уровне security, конечно).